# R: Extract column information from list of data frames using lapply, but produce NA if column name does not exist

Tags: lapply

I have a list of data frames named flplotmeta. The data frames have some columns in common, but not all.

I want to create a new list of data frames extracting the information contained in the column names "PID" and "PlotSize_m2"

"PID" is a column name present in all data frames. However, "PlotSize_m2" is only present in some of the data frames in my list. Where it isn't present, I want R to return NA in my new list of data frames.

I have the code below, which would work if "PlotSize_m2" was a column present in each data frame:

`fleffort <- lapply(flplotmeta, function(x) {x <- x[, c("PID","PlotSize_m2")]})`

If I try to run this, of course I get the error below:

Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 1, c("PID", "PlotSize_m2")) :
colonnes non définies sélectionnées

How can I modify this code to solve my problem, and output a list of data frames of size [n x 2]?